# Get the type of selected file by JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am writing a program to select file from the `JFileChooser`. How can I get the file type (e.g. is that file is "**.txt**" or "**.html**" of "**.dat**", etc.. )
I have the following code. what should i have to add extra lines?

```
JFileChooser choice = new JFileChooser();
int option = choice.showOpenDialog(this);
if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
     String path=choice.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
     String filename=choice.getSelectedFile().getName();
     System.out.println(path);
     listModel.addElement(path);
     System.out.println(filename);
}
```

Comment: If you simply want the extension: Since you have the filename, simply select all the characters including the last dot from your filename string.

Answer (score 8):

Use [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and [String#lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29):

`filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."),filename.length())`

Comment: This helped out a lot and used standard String objects to solve the problem without the need for external lib's. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to `split` or `substring`, you can use [Guava library Files](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) ([getFileExtention](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#getFileExtension%28java.lang.String%29)):

```
String extension = Files.getFileExtension(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will useful.

```
File f = choice.getSelectedFile();
String fileType = choice.getTypeDescription(f);
```